# moment.js date/time comparisons

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code:

```
var timeCutoff = moment('05:00PM', 'h:mmA').format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mmA")
var testTime = moment('11:00AM', 'h:mmA').format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mmA");

if(testTime < timeCutoff){
    console.log(testTime + " before " + timeCutoff);
}
else{
    console.log(testTime + " after " + timeCutoff);
}
```

The idea here is if now's time is **before** 5PM, do something. If the time is **after** 5PM, do something else.

Here is the problem I am experiencing:

testTime is set to ('11:00AM', 'h:mmA') and logs the "after" condition which is unexpected.
testTime is set to ('12:00PM', 'h:mmA') and logs the "after" condition which is unexpected.
testTime is set to ('01:00PM', 'h:mmA') and logs the "before" condition which is expected.
testTime is set to ('09:00PM', 'h:mmA') and logs the "after" condition which is expected.

I'm currently using moment.js 2.17.1

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for `isBefore`: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `isBefore()` method.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

```
var timeCutoff = moment('05:00PM', 'h:mmA');
var testTime = moment('11:00AM', 'h:mmA');

if(testTime.isBefore(timeCutoff)) {
  console.log(testTime.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mmA") + " before " + timeCutoff.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mmA"));
}
else
{
  console.log(testTime.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mmA") + " after " + timeCutoff.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mmA"));
}
```

Comment: Using if(testTime.isBefore(timeCutoff)) results in "testTime.isBefore is not a function" being logged to the console.

Comment: Do you still call `.format()` when you declare the `testTime` variable?  If so, then `testTime` will be a `string` not a `moment` instance. See my example.

Comment: It seems that .format() is strictly for presentation then?

Comment: Yes, it is the thing that lets you "render" or "translate" a moment instance into a string.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for your help.